# How to trigger onblur in Jasmine unit test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a function which logs something out onblur on a field.
How can I trigger the onblur function in unit test?

```
inputFunction() {
    const inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea');

    inputElements[0].onblur = () => {
        return console.log('test');
    };
}
```

Spec file:

```
describe('inputFunction', () => {
    it('should', function() {
        // data
        const ctrl = new inputController();

        const inputs = [angular.element('<input type="text">Test</input>'), angular.element('<input type="text">test</input>')];
        spyOn(document, 'querySelectorAll').and.returnValue(inputs);

        inputs[0].triggerHandler('blur');

        // when
        const expect = ctrl.inputFunction();

        // expect
        expect(expect).toEqual('test');
    });
});
```

Tried with `inputs[0].triggerHandler('blur');` but it doesn't work, it doesn't go inside the onblur function in my Unit Test.

How can I trigger `onblur` and go inside the onblur function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing: blur emulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681595/testing-blur-emulate)

Comment: No, I already tried that one :(

Answer (score 4):

I succeeded to triggered an event with the following code in my unit test:

```js
const inputEvent = new InputEvent('blur');
inputs[0].dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
```

Comment: Thanks @OL CO, I used your answer and added the ```fixture.detectChanges();``` after each event, then it finally worked!

Answer (score 1):

My solution to a similar problem is based on the the first answer but I had to add this line after each event:

`fixture.detectChanges();`

My code is different to your question, but I suppose the gist is relatively clear:

```
  it('should show the required error message when there is no value in the first name input field', () => {

    // Arrange
    const inputElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#inputFirstName')).nativeElement as HTMLElement;

    // Act
    const focusEvent = new InputEvent('focus');
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(focusEvent);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const blurEvent = new InputEvent('blur');
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(blurEvent);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const firstSpanElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#inputFirstName + .form-validation > span:first-child'));

    // Assert
    expect(firstSpanElement).toBeTruthy();
  })
```